# Android Studio Layout Editor incorrect display

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout-editor

I am using the latest version of android studio (stable) as of date, 3.2.1, freshly in stalled. However, when I'm opening a project, the layout editor does not display the attributes like what it usually shows on the right side of the layout editor when a view is selected.

The layout width, height, constraints (for constraint layout) are not showing up, and many other attributes.

I'm using windows 10, 1803. All fully updated.

But when I open the same project on my mac, the layout editor works well. Also if I'm using the latest version of android studio (canary). I only have this issue on android studio (stable).

Screenshots below to show that it's not showing what it should:

[image]
Any idea how to fix these issue?
This I've tried:
1) Invalidate caches and restart
2) Sync project with gradle files
3) Sync project with file system
4) Clean project > Rebuild Project
5) Reinstall android studio

None have worked so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating gradle version, android version, compile sdk version, build tools version, which can be found on

File > Project Structure >

** Project - for gradle and plugin version
(Currently using 4.10.2 for gradle, 3.4.0-alpha02 for plugin)

** App (under modules) - for compile sdk, and build tools version (Currently using API 28 for compile sdk, 28.0.3 for build tools version)